# Update position of nodes by force simulation, d3 version 4

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to move my nodes (and links) by force in d3 graph. The nodes add dynamically to the graph. I've looked through pile of examples, but they are based on d3 outdated version with force.layout instead of forceSimulation. 
I've tried many options and cases and nothing is working, the browser draws circle in the upper left part of svg.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="graph.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="graph">

    <script>
        var graph = new myGraph("#graph");
        graph.addNode("A");
        graph.addNode("B");
        graph.addLink("A", "B");
    </script>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

graph.js

```
function myGraph(el) {

var graph = this.graph = {
    "nodes":[{"name": "a"}],
    "links":[{"source":0,"target":1}]
};

this.addNode = function (name) {
    graph["nodes"].push({"name":name});
    update();
}

var findNode = function (name) {
    for (var i in graph["nodes"]) if (graph["nodes"][i]["name"] === name) return graph["nodes"][i];
}

this.addLink = function (source, target) {
    graph["links"].push({"source":findNode(source),"target":findNode(target)});
    update();
}

var vis = d3.select(el).append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 578)
    .attr("height", 300);

var nodes = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(graph.nodes);

var links = vis.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(graph.links);

var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-10))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter());

var update = function () {

    var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(graph.links);

    link.enter().insert("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    link.exit().remove();

    var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(graph.nodes);

    node.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("x", "-8px")
        .attr("y", "-8px");

    node.append("text")
        .attr("class", "nodetext")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name });

    node.exit().remove();

    force.on("tick", move);

    function move() {
        links.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
             .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
             .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
             .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        nodes.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
             .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
             .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
    };

    force.restart();

}

update();

}
```

[Link to jsFiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/1jL19bzc/5/)

There should be node and link variables (instead of all nodes and links) in move function, but browser produces error in this case:

d3.v4.min.js:4 Error:  attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(undefined,undefi…".

Help me, please, to make it running like it should be!

Comment: could you put together a working example on JSFiddle perhaps ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy thanks for idea! I added the link to the post

Comment: @user6731538 did you manage to solve this issue ?